# The PokeAPI is only sending 1 element to my frontend, using node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to build a Pokemon app using vanilla js on the frontend and Node/Express js on the backend. I'm fetching from the API on the backend and sending it to the frontend but it's only sending the first element from the API.

I'm also getting the error 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client'

Image result: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrPMr.png)

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const app = express();
const port = 1337;

app.use(cors());


if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test'){
    app.use(morgan('combined'));
}

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.method);
    console.log(req.path);
    next();
});

// Hämtade moduler
const index = require('./routes/index');

// Lägg till route
app.use('/', index);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let err = new Error("Not Found");
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if(res.headesSent){
        return next(err);
    }

    res.status(err.status || 500).json({
        "errors": [
            {
                "status": err.status,
                "title": err.message,
                "detail": err.message
            }
        ]
    })
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example API listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

***index.js***

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

router.get("/",  async (req, res) => {
    async function foo(){
        await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
             return getPokemonData(data)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })

    async function getPokemonData(pokemon){
        await pokemon.results.map(poke => {
            res.json(poke.url)
        })
    }
    }

    foo()
});

module.exports = router;
```

***Frontend - script.js***

```
const pokemonApplication = {

    btnGenerate: document.querySelector('.btnGetPokemon'),
    putMain: document.querySelector('.pokemon'),
    headingName: document.createElement('h2'),

    imgCont: document.createElement('img'),

    getPokemon: ()=> {

        const getFromApi = async () => {
            await fetch('http://localhost:1337')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);

                // const imgPokemon = data.sprites.other['official-artwork']['front_default']
                // const namePokemon = data.species.name;

                // // Append image
                
                // pokemonApplication.imgCont.src = imgPokemon;
                // pokemonApplication.putMain.prepend(pokemonApplication.imgCont)

                // // Append name
                // pokemonApplication.headingName.append(namePokemon);
                // pokemonApplication.putMain.prepend(pokemonApplication.headingName);
            })
        }

        pokemonApplication.btnGenerate.addEventListener('click', getFromApi);
    }
}

pokemonApplication.getPokemon();
```

Comment: Why you pass by a backend local and not fetch directly from the pokeAPI?

Comment: @Patfreeze I making this project to get familiar with Node/Express js. So I want to make the fetch on the backend and recive it at the frontend.

Comment: So I suggest you to console.log in your backend to make sure you fetch everything you need and you need also resend information as a string JSON. With **JSON.stringify**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Map in javascript will loop thought all pokemon.
Only one "res" can be send to client.

So the first one was send all other failed. Thats why you have
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]

```js
    async function getPokemonData(pokemon){
        await pokemon.results.map(poke => {
            res.json(poke.url) // This is not good
        })
    }
```

Something similar as:

```js
    async function getPokemonData(pokemon){
        const pokUrls = await pokemon.results.map(poke => {
            return poke.url
        })
    res.json(pokUrls)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, what should I use in order to send all of the elements and not just 1?

Comment: Just edit my post for a similar example. Ajust if needed.

Comment: It solved my problem. I have one more question. I want to extract further information about each Pokemon. In the getPokemonData function I used fetch(poke.url) to fetch the information from each url. When I return it and res.json the result it give back null on each element.

Comment: Nice if it solve your problem, add a check mark that solves it . By the way, without code to see is difficult to help... the function **console.log()** is your best friend. 

Comment: I solved the other question I asked u, I kept getting undefined because I wasnt handling each promise I was getting, so I handled it through Promised.all